# How to make intl to generate dart files with null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter package `intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2` still generates dart files that don't follow null safety practices.
I also tried adding this with no success:

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```

It still generates folder without null safety.

How to force `intl` package to generate null safety dart files?

Comment: Use intl: 0.17.0 (without nullsafety.2) as it's the current stable release for null safety at this time. [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/changelog)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here are 3 steps to troubleshoot this:

1. First of all, update intl dependency in pubspec.yaml to this:

intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2

2. If still doesn't work, then add these 2 fields in the root.

dependency_overrides: intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2

3. Generation also can happen via plugin in Android Studio. I used old one (v 0.12) and after I updated to (v 0.14) it started to generate null safety dart files for localization.

I think I stepped on every rock here.